# What word can be used to describe mathematically increasing dimension?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for a concise way to describe expanding the dimension of an object, i.e. taking a square and turning it into a cube.

> In order to turn a square into a cube, you _____ it into three dimensions.

Comment: @Hank To turn a square into a cube, you XXXX it.

Comment: simply "extend" ?

Comment: @Graffito I want something more specific than just that

Comment: To tun a square into a cube, you project it into 3-space.
To turn a cube into a hypercube, you project it into 4-space.

Comment: Right, project is correct. :)

Comment: You could say it's been "dimensionally **augmented**", resulting in a cube.

Comment: Why is everyone commenting and nobody answering? The instructions are clear "Do not use comments to answer questions". The reasons are clear: neither the poster or anyone else can judge the answers as they are unsubstantiated, can't be voted down and the question is indexed as unanswered.

Comment: @David people answer in comments when they don't think the question is worth a full answer (and should probably be closed). If the answer is going to be 'blah' with no explanation possible or a trivial explanation, then the question really isn't that great. That's why SWR's are (reasonably) maligned.

Comment: @Mitch — So they think the instructions in the comment box don't apply to them?

Comment: I'm with Mitch. Outside the specialised field of geometry, the question is meaningless.

Within the field of geometry, the questions should have been answered in every single text book that we in the UK would call 'A' level, and some  for lower levels. Whether that's what the USA would call 'high school' I'm not sure…

Comment: @David Not all "responses" constitute as a "good answer". Especially when the question isn't 100% clear. The instructions are not black and white.

Comment: @David [Related Meta post about answers in comments](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9921/142322).

Comment: The stack exchange community is absolute shite, and this is a great example of why. A bunch of narcissists arguing about fucking rules and shit rather than answering the question. For fucks sakes, this site is almost as toxic as youtube.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: "Outside the specialised field of geometry, the question is meaningless." Agreed. (OP should consider posting the exact same question on math.stackexchange.) "Within the field of geometry, the questions [sic] should have been answered in every single text book that we in the UK would call 'A' level..." I don't believe this. If an A-level geometry textbook would contain the word, then surely *you yourself* would be able to name the word and answer OP's question. (A conjecture about the contents of a textbook you haven't read isn't an answer.)